# Rock Generator says it doesn't work in 2.8

Tags: add-on

I've tried all the steps from searching other threads about using the Rock Generator in 2.8.

Every time I install the add-on  there is a yellow exclamation that says the add-on needs to be updated for 2.8.

Any ideas on how to get it working?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TIKSRes4IGI

Answer (score 1):

The error message you're seeing means that the add-on has not been updated for 2.8.  Until it is, it will not work in Blender 2.8.

You can either use it in Blender 2.79 (assuming it's compatible with 2.79), or wait for the add-on to be updated for 2.8.

Comment: that's one of the bummers of 2.80, everything needs to be updated, but I guess the benefits out way the cost.